# Как лучше сделать бекап папки с файлами для приложения

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот у меня в приложении с маркерами есть основная папка, в которой есть подпапки, где хранятся тхт файлы с точками для разных карт, а также сделанные пользователем ресурсоемкие (~4мб) фотографии к маркерам. Если тхт файл какой-нибудь карты поломается, то приложение будет выдавать ошибку. Вся эта основная папка со всем содержимым со временем может быть очень ресурсоемкая, 5гб не предел, в основном из-за фотографий.

Вопрос в том, как лучше организовать бекап такой основной папки, чтобы в случае чего просто заменить ее и все? То ли просто копировать рядом с пометкой backup, то ли еще как-то..

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Какие требования к бэкапам? Какие варианты вы уже рассматривали?

Comment: По требованиям я пока и сам не знаю, вот и спрашиваю как люди делают.. Мои варианты, это делать копии файлов..

Answer (score 1):

Если приложением пользуетесь только вы, то можно делать рядом копию папки, если хочется и места не жалко. Если же приложением пользуются и другие пользователи, то делать копии гигабайтов фотографий внутри телефона не очень хорошая идея, вряд ли пользователи будут рады. Делайте бэкапы текстовых файлов, они много места не занимают, а фотографии пусть остаются на своих местях. В приложении сделать так, чтоб оно не крашилось, если какая-то фотография отсутствует или не читается, а показывать заглушку. Так делает, например, WhatsApp. База данных с разговорами бэкапится в соседнюю папку, а медиафайлы не трогаются. Если картинку удалили, то в чате на ее месте заглушка.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, возможно сделаю бекап только тхт файлов, они и вправду маленькие.. Отсутствие картинок приложение не крашит, там просто пустое место сейчас..

Comment: У меня эта основная папка со всеми фотографиами и тхт конфигами карт лежит на внутреннем накопителе, storage/emulated/0, и не удаляется с удалением программы, а остается, и ее удаление надо производить вручную.. Не знаю, нормальная ли такая практика.. Сделал так на всякий случай, чтобы при случайном удалении программы люди не потеряли свои фотографии и точки..